# Materialize a href buttons inside a React Router Link Component

Tags: javascript, css, react-router, materialize

I'm trying to use materialize.css to stylize a signup button. Materialize creates buttons using the anchor tag e.g

```html
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Button</a>
```

which renders this:

[image]

Currently I'm using this in a Meteor project using react-router and trying to wrap a react-router < Link > component around it

```html
<Link to="signup"><a className="waves-effect waves-light btn blue-grey darken-1"><i className="material-icons left">cloud</i>Register Here!</a></Link>
```

With this implementation I'm getting this dom warning:

"Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of . See App > Link > a > ... > a."

[image]

How would I go about getting around this?

Comment: Have you tried applying the `waves-effect` classes etc directly on the `<Link>` element?

Comment: That worked thank-you!